# How do I convert a Vector of bytes (u8) to a string?

Tags: rust

I am trying to write simple TCP/IP client in Rust and I need to print out the buffer I got from the server.

How do I convert a `Vec<u8>` (or a `&[u8]`) to a `String`?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

To convert a slice of bytes to a string slice (assuming a UTF-8 encoding):

```rust
use std::str;

//
// pub fn from_utf8(v: &[u8]) -> Result<&str, Utf8Error>
//
// Assuming buf: &[u8]
//

fn main() {

    let buf = &[0x41u8, 0x41u8, 0x42u8];

    let s = match str::from_utf8(buf) {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
    };

    println!("result: {}", s);
}
```

The conversion is in-place, and does not require an allocation. You can create a `String` from the string slice if necessary by calling `.to_owned()` on the string slice ([other options are available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31331356/155423)).

If you are sure that the byte slice is valid UTF-8, and you don’t want to incur the overhead of the validity check, there is an unsafe version of this function, `from_utf8_unchecked`, which has the same behavior but skips the check.

If you need a String instead of a &str, you may also consider `String::from_utf8` instead.

The library references for the conversion function:

- [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html)
- [`std::str::from_utf8_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html)
- [`std::string::String::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8)

Comment: You may want to add that this is possible because Vec coerces to slices

Comment: Although it's true that `from_utf8` doesn't allocate, it may be worth mentioning that it needs to scan the data to validate utf-8 correctness. So this is not an O(1) operation (which one may think at first)

Answer (score 171):

I prefer [`String::from_utf8_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy):

```
fn main() {
    let buf = &[0x41u8, 0x41u8, 0x42u8];
    let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(buf);
    println!("result: {}", s);
}
```

It turns invalid UTF-8 bytes into � and so no error handling is required. It's good for when you don't need that and I hardly need it. You actually get a `String` from this. It should make printing out what you're getting from the server a little easier.

Sometimes you may need to use the [`into_owned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#method.into_owned) method since it's clone on write.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the `into_owned()` suggestion! Was exactly was I was looking for (this makes it become a proper `String` which you can return as a return value from a method, for example).

Comment: � is Unicode U+FFFD (UTF-8 sequence 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD (octal 357 277 275)), '[REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65280)'. In some text editors it can be searched for in regular expression mode by `\x{FFFD}`.

Answer (score 99):

If you actually have a *vector of bytes* (`Vec<u8>`) and want to convert to  a `String`, the most efficient is to reuse the allocation with [`String::from_utf8`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8):

```
fn main() {
    let bytes = vec![0x41, 0x42, 0x43];
    let s = String::from_utf8(bytes).expect("Found invalid UTF-8");
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Comment: Edit: Note that as mentioned by @Bjorn Tipling you might think you can use `String::from_utf8_lossy` instead here, then you don't need the `expect` call, but the input to that is a slice of bytess (`&'a [u8]`). OTOH, there's also `from_utf8_unchecked`. "If you are sure that the byte slice is valid UTF-8, and you don't want to incur the overhead of the conversion, there is an unsafe version of this function [`from_utf8_lossy]`, `from_utf8_unchecked`, which has the same behavior but skips the checks."

Comment: Note that you can use `&vec_of_bytes` to convert back into a slice of bytes, as listed in the examples of `from_utf8_lossy`.https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy

Comment: @JamesRay is there a way to get the behavior of `from_utf8_lossy` without reallocating? If I start with a `Vec` and then take a reference to it before converting it to a string as in `String::from_utf8_lossy(&my_vec)` I will end up reallocating memory when I don't actually need to.

Comment: Oh nevermind. `from_utf8_lossy` returns a `Cow<str>`, not a String. If there are no invalid characters then it won't reallocate, but if there are it will.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I just needed to turn the numbers into a string, not the numbers to letters according to some encoding, so I did

```
fn main() {
    let bytes = vec![0x41, 0x42, 0x43];
    let s = format!("{:?}", &bytes);
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Comment: This is what I have tried, but felt that it might be wrong or something. Perhaps I'll stick to this for now.

Answer (score 4):

To optimally convert a `Vec<u8>` possibly containing non-UTF-8 characters/byte sequences into a UTF-8 `String` *without any unneeded allocations*, you'll want to optimistically try calling `String::from_utf8()` then resort to `String::from_utf8_lossy()`.

```rust
let buffer: Vec<u8> = ...;

let utf8_string = String::from_utf8(buffer)
    .map_err(|non_utf8| String::from_utf8_lossy(non_utf8.as_bytes()).into_owned())
    .unwrap();
```

The approach suggested in the other answers will result in *two* owned buffers in memory even in the happy case (with valid UTF-8 data in the vector): one with the original `u8` bytes and the other in the form of a `String` owning its characters. This approach will instead attempt to consume the `Vec<u8>` and marshal it as a Unicode `String` directly and only failing that will it allocate room for a new string containing the lossily UTF-8 decoded output.

Answer (score -3):

v.iter().map(|&c| char::from(c)).collect()

Comment: This is really, really bad approach. From multiple sides. Much better to use the accepted answer.

Comment: In what way is it bad? It generates a proper String from bytes, not trying to pretend the bytes are UTF-8 encoded. Very common case. Such data is returned from various external services. Especially technical descriptions of system state. You want to print it, search it for substrings etc.

Comment: It is both slower than `String::from_utf8()` and does not handles UTF-8 correctly. Yes, sometimes you only need ASCII, but `String::from_utf8()` handles that fine (and faster), as all ASCII is also valid UTF-8. And wanting Unicode _is_ a common need, which this answer dos not handle properly. It will compile, and result in gibberish.

Comment: When you have some control characters in the binary vector then it might not be a valid UTF-8. You just want those bytes as successive characters not trying to decode anything or interpret. Is it slower? Probably - it has to make an allocation. I'd say you need a proper tool for each case.

Comment: You have non-ASCII control characters and you want a UTF-8 `String`? This is a really, really rare and weird case. I don't think it deserves an answer on SO. And even if you think it does, it at least deserves a big warning that it does not handle Unicode properly and for 99.9% of the cases you want the accepted answer.

Comment: I come from Python where it is pretty normal to have a Unicode string with any characters in it. Not a UTF8 encoded stream of bytes, but a Unicode string like: '\u0001\u00FF'. Why can't we have it in Rust?

Comment: If this is Unicode, even partially, then your solution doesn't work anyway. And in Rust, unlike Python, `String` is guaranteed fully UTF-8. If you want something that is partially UTF-8, leave it as `Vec<u8>`. You may use crates like [`bstr`](https://docs.rs/bstr/latest/bstr/) to do various string operations on it.

Comment: Each Unicode code point from 0x00 to 0xFF is well defined. This method doesn't generate any other code points by definition. It doesn't even touch the idea of internal representation of those code points / UTF-8.