# How to create a String directly?

Tags: string, rust

Is there any way to avoid calling `.to_string()` when I need a string? For example:

```
fn func1(aaa: String) -> ....
```

And instead of

```
func1("fdsfdsfd".to_string())
```

can I do something like this:

```
func1(s"fdsfdsfd")
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

TL;DR:

As of [Rust 1.9](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-190-2016-05-26), `str::to_string`, `str::to_owned`, `String::from`, `str::into` all have the same performance characteristics. Use whichever you prefer.

---

The most obvious and idiomatic way to convert a string slice (`&str`) to an owned string (`String`) is to use [`ToString::to_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string). This works for any type that implements [`Display`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html). This includes string slices, but also integers, IP addresses, paths, errors, and so on.

Before Rust 1.9, the `str` implementation of `to_string` leveraged the [formatting infrastructure](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.1.0/src/libcollections/string.rs#L1047). While it worked, it was overkill and not the most performant path.

A lighter solution was to use [`ToOwned::to_owned`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#tymethod.to_owned), which is implemented for types that have a "borrowed" and an "owned" pair. It is [implemented in an efficient manner](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.1.0/src/libcollections/str.rs#L404-L411).

Another lightweight solution is to use [`Into::into`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#tymethod.into) which leverages [`From::from`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#tymethod.from). This is also [implemented efficiently](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.1.0/src/libcollections/string.rs#L1074).

---

For your *specific* case, the best thing to do is to accept a `&str`, as [thirtythreeforty answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31331811/155423). Then you need to do **zero allocations**, which is the best outcome.

In general, I will probably use `into` if I need to make an allocated string — it's only 4 letters long ^_^. When answering questions on Stack Overflow, I'll use `to_owned` as it's much more obvious what is happening.

Answer (score 16):

No, the `str::to_string()` method is the canonical way of creating a `String` from an `&'static str` (a string literal).  I even like it for the reason you dislike it: it's a little verbose.  Because it involves a heap allocation, you should think twice before invoking it in cases such as these.  Also note that since [Rust gained impl specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210), `str::to_string` is no slower than `str::to_owned` or its ilk.

However, what you really want here is a `func1` that can easily be passed any string, be it a `&str` or a `String`.  Because a `String` will [Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) to a `&str`, you can have `func1` accept an `&str`, thereby avoiding the String allocation altogether.  See this example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20func1%28s%3A%20%26str%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20s%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20let%20allocated_string%3A%20String%20%3D%20%22owned%20string%22.to_string%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20func1%28%22static%20string%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20func1%28%26allocated_string%29%3B%0A%7D&version=stable)):

```
fn func1(s: &str) {
    println!("{}", s);
}

fn main() {
   let allocated_string: String = "owned string".to_string();
   func1("static string");
   func1(&allocated_string);
}
```

Comment: `to_string` is still used by default, even if it's technically a bit slower. With specialization it won't be, though.

Comment: according to alex crichton, `to_string` is the idiomatic way to convert a `str` to a `String`: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/26176

Comment: @steveklabnik at that GitHub link, you said that "`to_owned()` is better for generic code." Why is that?

Comment: `to_string` is definitely the **idiomatic** choice — it's just not currently the performant choice. I [made a comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/19708#issuecomment-66930515) about six months ago where replacing `to_string` made my code take 87% of the previous time.

Comment: thirtythreeforty, because it's a generic way of turning a borrowed value into an owned one.

Comment: "Using `to_owned()` fully captures the reason that a conversion is required at a particular spot in our code." https://users.rust-lang.org/t/to-string-vs-to-owned-for-string-literals/1441/6?u=rofrol

Comment: `to_string` feels wrong to me, as its the method that returns the "human-readable version of a value". That this coincides with the owned version of a `&str` is really just a coincidence; there's nothing stopping `str::to_string` from returning `My stringified string is: ...`. For instance, the numeric types all have `to_string` defined totally separately from the notion of ownership (they're all `Copy` anyway). On the other hand, `str::to_owned` *must* return just the owned version of the `&str`; nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 6):

[dtolnay](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/to-string-vs-to-owned-for-string-literals/1441/6?u=rofrol):

> I now strongly prefer `to_owned()` for string literals over either of `to_string()` or `into()`.
>
> What is the difference between `String` and `&str`? An unsatisfactory answer is “one is a string and the other is not a string” because obviously both are strings. Taking something that is a string and converting it to a string using `to_string()` seems like it misses the point of why we are doing this in the first place, and more importantly misses the opportunity to document this to our readers.
>
> The difference between String and &str is that one is owned and one is not owned. Using `to_owned()` fully captures the reason that a conversion is required at a particular spot in our code.
>
> ```
> struct Wrapper {
>     s: String
> }
>    
> // I have a string and I need a string. Why am I doing this again?
> Wrapper { s: "s".to_string() }
>    
> // I have a borrowed string but I need it to be owned.
> Wrapper { s: "s".to_owned() }
> ```

[vitalyd](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/to-string-vs-to-owned-for-string-literals/1441/7):

> Not if you mentally read `to_string` as `to_String`

Comment: Did you mean to include vitalyd's comment?