# What is the difference between these 3 ways of declaring a string in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

```
let hello1 = "Hello, world!";
let hello2 = "Hello, world!".to_string();
let hello3 = String::from("Hello, world!");
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
let hello1 = "Hello, world!";
```

This creates a *string slice* (`&str`). Specifically, a `&'static str`, a string slice that lives for the entire duration of the program. No heap memory is allocated; the data for the string lives within the binary of the program itself.

```
let hello2 = "Hello, world!".to_string();
```

This uses the formatting machinery to format *any* type that implements `Display`, creating an owned, allocated string (`String`). In versions of Rust before 1.9.0 (specifically because of [this commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/fc8cf9c5afd531e825b3ae9a57f618c149dd3893)), this is slower than directly converting using `String::from`. In version 1.9.0 and after, calling `.to_string()` on a string literal is the same speed as `String::from`.

```
let hello3 = String::from("Hello, world!");
```

This converts a string slice to an owned, allocated string (`String`) in an efficient manner.

```
let hello4 = "hello, world!".to_owned();
```

The same as `String::from`.

See also:

- [How to create a String directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31331356/155423)
- [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24158114/155423)

Comment: Thanks for putting in the effort you have in your answers, Shepmaster. For anyone coming here wondering, as I did, where `.into()` fits into all of this, this is answered by the [How to create a String directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31331356/155423) link in this answer.

Comment: Now we know they have all the same performance, is there a chosen one in the Rust community?

Comment: @DrumM each one has its own places to be used. The `ToString`, `Into` / `From`, and `ToOwned` traits all mean different *conceptual* things, it just happens that they all do the same concrete thing for strings. My personal preference is to use `"string literal".into()` if it works, otherwise `String::from("string literal")`. In other cases, I'll change a function to accept `impl Into<String>` so I don't have to care at all at the call site.

Comment: so is to_string() the same as String::from()? what do you mean by formatting machinery?

Comment: @ezio *is `to_string()` the same as `String::from()`* — not always, no. It should be the same when used on a string type though. *formatting machinery* — the part of the standard library that implements all the functionality of tools like `println!` or `write!`. The things documented by [`std::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/)

Comment: Useful info https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-convert-str-to-string/12160/4 - to_string or String::from or to_owned are the same, just a matter of taste.