# How to specialize on the stable channel before specialization is stabilized?

Tags: generics, rust

How can I achieve the following (pseudo Rust) with stable Rust?

```
pub fn read<T: Read>(stream: T) {
    let stream = if T implements BufRead {
        stream
    } else {
        BufReader::new(stream)
    };

    // Work with `stream`
}
```

I know about [impl specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), however I want to achieve the same thing with stable Rust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of pure Rust, with difficulty:

- Stable does not have specialization
- Rust does not have down-casting

That being said, there are alternatives such as the [`query_interfaces`](https://crates.io/crates/query_interface) crate which promote principled down-casting.

In essence, you want to let the caller tell you whether `BufRead` is implemented for the stream in question. `query_interfaces` or a dedicated purpose solution can be created to ship "optional" v-pointers.

However, I would simply require `BufRead` to be implement by `stream`. The caller can always wrap their `stream` with `BufRead::new` if they need.

Answer (score 4):

**You don't**. The *entire reason* that the RFC exists is because it wasn't possible before!

As "proof", consider `str::to_string`. Before specialization existed, `str::to_string` used the exact same mechanism as all the other implementors of `ToString`, which meant that it had to build up and use the formatting infrastructure. This is relatively expensive and benchmarks actively [showed the difference between `str::to_string` and `str::to_owned` or `String::from`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31331356/155423). After specialization was enabled, the Rust compiler used it for `str::to_string`, and the benchmarks improved.

If the *Rust compiler* couldn't specialize before specialization, it's *highly unlikely* that other code could find some way to work around it in a generic manner.

---

For your specific case, I agree that you should just accept something implementing `BufRead` (`fn read<T: BufRead>(stream: T)`).