# How does String::from("") & "".to_string() differ in Rust?

Tags: rust

How does `String::from("")` & `"".to_string()` differ in Rust?

Is there any difference in stack and heap allocation in both cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a String directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331356/how-to-create-a-string-directly)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How does `String::from("")` & `"".to_string()` differ in Rust?

They're part of different protocols (traits): [std::convert::From](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) and [alloc::string::ToString](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/string/trait.ToString.html)<sup>[0]</sup>.

However, when it comes to `&str`/`String` they do the same thing (as does `"".to_owned()`).

> Is there any difference in stack and heap allocation in both cases?

As joelb's link indicates, before Rust 1.9 `"".to_string()` was markedly slower than the alternatives as it went through the entire string formatting machinery. That's no longer the case.

---

<sub>[0] `ToString` is also automatically implemented if the structure implements `Display`<sup>[1]</sup></sub>

<sub>[1] functionally `s.to_string()` is equivalent to `format!("{}", s)`, it's usually recommended to *not* implement `ToString` directly, unless bypassing the formatting machinery can provide significant performance improvements (which is why `str`/`String` do it)</sub>

Comment: if they do the same thing and have the same performance why are different traits used?

Comment: Because the traits have different purposes, they just happen to do the same thing for strings. `ToString` is auto-implemented for `Display`, it makes sense that Display-ing a string would be an identity, so you get a `String` with the same content as the original `str`. `From` converts A to B, it also makes sense that converting an `&str` to a `String` would be an identity allocation. Same with `ToOwned`, the owned version of an `&str` is the `String` with the same content. Maybe the core team could have left out `String::from(&str)` but... why?

Comment: so .to_string() is restricted to use only with &str's whereas String::from() can come from any type which has the right trait to allow a string to be generated from it?

Comment: No, both work with any type for which they're implemented. `to_string` works with any type which implements `Display` (or `ToString` but that's rarely if ever implemented directly), and `String::from` works with any type for which `From<Type> for String` is implemented.

Comment: Ok in that case what is the difference in functionality between the two traits?