# How to decide between to_string() and String_From()?

Tags: string, rust

I'm working through the MSLearn tutorial on Rust and in the topic on Strings I encounter this in an example that intentionally includes an error: "The compiler suggests that we can use the .to_string() function to make the conversion. In our examples, we use the String::from(&str) method."

So the tutorial writers must have had a reason for preferring String::from() over .to_string(). As a newcomer, should I assume that I should just stick with the one, hoping that someday I'll know enough to make my own choice?  Or is this explainable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between these 3 ways of declaring a string in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149831/what-is-the-difference-between-these-3-ways-of-declaring-a-string-in-rust). Also [How does String::from("") & "".to_string() differ in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61475158/11082165)

Comment: From the answer there, you would previously avoid `.to_string()` for this since it would incur a unnecessary performance hit, but that is no longer the case. So use whatever way you prefer.

Comment: They probably had a reason, but we can't read their mind. The Rust community is divided on what is better, though, each has its own advantages. Personally I prefer `.to_owned()`, but recently I started to think that maybe `.to_string()` is better, and `String::from()` is also an option I sometimes reconsider.

Comment: Honestly, I have never understood why the trait `ToString` was even created in the first place. If you want to print some data to display them, then use either `Display` or `Debug`. If you need to convert the data into a string, use `Into<String>`. If you want to serialize your data, use `serde`. I've never met an other usecase, and I feel like `ToString` is just a mixup

Comment: @jthulhu Integers, for example, don't implement `Into<String>` (and rightfully so), and using `Display` is cumbersome (and slow). `ToString` is essentially a shorthand for single-element-to-string `Display`