# Convert &[u8] to String

Tags: types, rust

I have a byte array which I would like to return as `std::string::String`. The other answers and docs I found were converting Vectors to strings.

How would I convert a byte array `&[u8]` to a `String`?

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076878/155423) does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 10):

It's working with [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html):

```
std::str::from_utf8(byte_array).unwrap().to_string();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1bf9314ca311992e1bdec327ad1faa51&version=stable&mode=debug)

Comment: If you want a `String`, you can also use: `String::from_utf8(byte_array.to_vec()).unwrap()`