# How can I convert a bytes::Bytes to a &str without making any copies?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, binary-data

I have a [`bytes::Bytes`](https://docs.rs/bytes/0.4.11/bytes/) (in this case its the body of a request in actix-web) and another function that expects a string slice argument: `foo: &str`. What is the proper way to convert the `bytes::Bytes` to `&str` so that no copy is made? I've tried `&body.into()` but I get:

```
the trait `std::convert::From<bytes::bytes::Bytes>` is not implemented for `str`
```

Here are the basic function signatures:

```
pub fn parse_body(data: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    // Do stuff
    // ....
    Ok("xyz")
}

fn consume_data(req: HttpRequest<AppState>, body: bytes::Bytes) -> HttpResponse {
    let foo = parse_body(&body);
    // Do stuff
    HttpResponse::Ok().into()
}
```

Comment: What should happen if the bytes aren't valid UTF8?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`Bytes` dereferences to `[u8]`](https://docs.rs/bytes/0.4.11/bytes/struct.Bytes.html#impl-Deref), so you can use any existing mechanism to convert `&[u8]` to a string.

```
use bytes::Bytes; // 0.4.10
use std::str;

fn example(b: &Bytes) -> Result<&str, str::Utf8Error> {
    str::from_utf8(b)
}
```

See also:

- [How do I convert a Vector of bytes (u8) to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19076719/155423)

> I've tried `&body.into()`

`From` and `Into` are only for infallible conversions. Not all arbitrary chunks of data are valid UTF-8.