# Efficient remove prefix from string including invalid bytes

Tags: rust

Here is the situation, I want to remove some invalid bytes(varint length of the string) in the front of the string, At first, I tried to use `drain` method, but as the doc says:

> Panics if the starting point or end point do not lie on a char
>   boundary, or if they're out of bounds.

So I tried to use for loop to `remove` the prefix

```rust
    let mut input = String::from_utf8_lossy(&[128,2,49]).into_owned();
    let len = 2;
    for _ in 0..len {
        input.remove(0);
    }
```

Is there any way to be more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unsound to ever create a `String` that contains invalid (i.e., non-UTF8) bytes, so you can't use `String` methods to deal with them. If you have a slice of `u8`s, some section of which is valid UTF-8, the best way to deal with it is to only convert the portion that is valid:

```
let raw_input: &'static [u8] = &[128, 2, 49];
let len = 2;
let input = str::from_utf8(raw_input[len..]).unwrap().to_owned();
```

If `raw_input[len..]` does not start with a valid UTF-8 character encoding, `str::from_utf8()` will return an `Err` value (which `.unwrap()` will turn into a panic), so this is only appropriate when you know that the UTF-8 data starts at `len`. This is different from the behavior of `from_utf8_lossy`, which converts invalid UTF-8 sequences to �, but if the string is meant to be well-formed UTF-8 except for the leading "garbage", `from_utf8_lossy` is not called for.

There is no need to use `unsafe` for this.

Also see: [How do I convert a Vector of bytes (u8) to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076719/how-do-i-convert-a-vector-of-bytes-u8-to-a-string)

Comment: Thanks for your explaination, it seems that I shouldn't use String as data structure to deal with the data.