# How do I convert MySQL BINARY columns I created with Node Buffers to strings in Rust?

Tags: mysql, node.js, rust

### What I did

- Stored a UUID as `BINARY(16)` in NodeJS using

```js
const uuid = Buffer.from('myEditedUuid');
```

(A followup to [How do I fetch binary columns from MySQL in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076722/how-do-i-fetch-binary-columns-from-mysql-in-rust))

### What I want to do

I want to fetch said UUID using Rust https://docs.rs/mysql/20.0.0/mysql/.
I am currently using `Vec<u8>` to gain said UUID:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Serialize)]
pub struct Policy {
    sub: String,
    contents: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Serialize)]
pub struct RawPolicy {
    sub: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    contents: Option<String>,
}

// fetch policies themselves
let policies: Vec<RawPolicy> = connection.query_map("SELECT sub, contents FROM policy", |(sub, contents)| {
    RawPolicy { sub, contents }
},)?;

// convert uuid to string
let processed = policies.into_iter().map(|policy| {
    let sub = policy.sub.unwrap();
    let sub_string = String::from_utf8(sub).unwrap().to_string();
    Policy {
        sub: sub_string,
        contents: policy.contents,
    }
}).collect();
```

### What my problem is

In Node, I would receive a Buffer from said database and use something like `uuidBUffer.toString('utf8');`
So in Rust, I try to use `String::from_utf8()`, but said Vec does not seem to be a valid utf8-vec:

```
panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: FromUtf8Error { bytes: [17, 234, 79, 61, 99, 181, 10, 240, 164, 224, 103, 175, 134, 6, 72, 71], error: Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 1, error_len: Some(1) } }'
```

### My question is

Is Using Vec correct way of fetching `BINARY`-Columns and if so, how do I convert them back to a string?

### Edit1:

Node seems to use Base 16 to Convert A string to a Buffer (`Buffer.from('abcd') => <Buffer 61 62 63 64>`).

Fetching my parsed UUID in Rust made With Buffer.from() gives me `Vec<u8> [17, 234, 79, 61, 99, 181, 10, 240, 164, 224, 103, 175, 134, 6, 72, 71]` which thows said utf8-Error.
Vec does not seem to be allowed by MySQL in Rust.

Comment: If your UUID is actually stored as binary data and not a string representation (e.g. hex), then you have to use `Vec<u8>` on Rust side, not `String`. `String` can only deal with valid UTF-8 data.

Comment: I did, this is what the PolicyRaw Struct is for. But at some point, I have to convert it back somehow.

Comment: I think that you either need to use `from_utf8_lossy` or `from_utf16_lossy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is simple:
You need to convert the BINARY to hex at you database Query or you code. So either try Using the HEX-Crate https://docs.rs/hex/0.4.2/hex/ or rewrite your Query:

### Rewriting The Query

```rust
let policies: Vec<RawPolicy> = connection.query_map("SELECT hex(sub), contents FROM policy", |(sub, contents)| {
 RawPolicy { sub, contents }
},)?;
```

Converts the sub to hex numbers. Now the resulting Vec can be converted using

```rust
let sub = policy.sub.unwrap();
let sub_string = String::from_utf8(sub).unwrap();
```

Comment: That was the solution. Rewriting The Query helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`from_utf8_lossy` can be used

```
let input = [17, 234, 79, 61, 99, 181, 10, 240, 164, 224, 103, 175, 134, 6, 72, 71];
let output = String::from_utf8_lossy(&input); // "\u{11}�O=c�\n��g��\u{6}HG"
```

Invalid characters will be replaced by `�`

The output `"\u{11}�O=c�\n��g��\u{6}HG"` is the same as the nodejs output `"\u0011�O=c�\n��g��\u0006HG"`.
Unless this string is to be send to a javascript runtime, it should be kept that way.

But if this string is to be send to a javascript runtime (browser or nodejs), then the unicode point notations`\u{x}` should be substituted to their equivalent notation in javascript

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c4b84d68a8b87fcc167ec848d49a964b)

`from_ut16_lossy` can be used as well

If some of the previous `�` are not utf-8 encoded but `utf-16`, they will be converted, if not the same `�` will be used to render them.

```
let input:&[u16] = &vec![17, 234, 79, 61, 99, 181, 10, 240, 164, 224, 103, 175, 134, 6, 72, 71];
println!("{}", String::from_utf16_lossy(input))
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0847b8e5881daf77bbe6cfd8d24fdbd7)

Comment: Thanks so far! My Value looks like `"sub":"\u0011�O=c�\n��g��\u0006HG"`. So there is still some piece of the puzzle missing

Comment: you mean you rather want to have the hex encoding of invalid characters

Comment: Best thing would be to have the plain string again I converted in NodejS before. F.Ex If I had a string 'abcd', node Gives me `<Buffer 61 62 63 64>` which I can store in my `BINARY`-Column. I just want to have my `abcd` in Rust again.

Comment: this one does just that: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9449bccdfb10508e3b34da9adfa3ff2. Btw, "a" encoding is not 61 but 97

Comment: But your UUID is not `abcd`. You can convert a `Vec<u8>` consisting of valid ASCII / UTF-8 bytes to string. You *can not* directly convert arbitrary bytes (such as a UUID) to a Rust string.

Comment: So what should I do then? @justinas

Comment: @CodingVampyre why do you want to convert to a `String`, what value do you think it would provide? Using `Vec<u8>` is the intended way to handle binary data.

Comment: it's a parsed UUID which is stored similar to https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/. I want to change it back into a string to send it to the client.

Comment: `uuid` crate has functions for formatting UUID as a string. You probably want the [hyphenated](https://docs.rs/uuid/0.8.1/uuid/struct.Uuid.html#method.to_hyphenated_ref) formatter which will format the string as hex with hyphens inbetween.